# Is there a Spring Security 4.x taglib for Facelets

Tags: spring, spring-security, facelets

I'm involved working in a project using Spring Security 4.x and JSF 2.2 with Facelets. I just noticed that spring security in this version have enabled by default the protection against Cross Site Request Forgery using request tokens, the case is that you have to put the tag `<sec:csrfMetaTags>` in many pages (if not, spring deny the request), the lib `spring-faces` is in 2.4.1 which hasn't these tags for Facelets (XHTML).

I tried to find an implementation in order to get working my project using these frameworks but I couldn't find any, do you know any adaptation?

In my case, I adapted just the part I needed (at this point), if there are no public adaptations, I'd be glad to put it into an open source project and try to adapt all the library.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I created a blog post explaining my solution:
http://halexv.blogspot.mx/2015/07/spring-security-4x-csrf-protection-for.html

Comment: do you need it only for form posts?

Comment: At this moment the functions I'm using are for csrf (two functions), I had already ported it but I saw many interesting functions.

Comment: There currently is no implementation for that, so you would have to create your own. There are more issues with Spring Faces and the Spring Security 4 combination as to methods etc. removed from Spring Security but still used in Spring Faces.

Comment: I created a blog post with my solution: http://halexv.blogspot.mx/2015/07/spring-security-4x-csrf-protection-for.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the spring taglib for the JSF which you can access from this link.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib

I believe you already know this. But your actual question is related to the **CRSF** which you have to add to all your pages. ***This in specific can be achieved by adding the token automatically to your forms as below***

**Create a util class and add a token generator**

```
static String getTokenForSession (HttpSession session) {
 String token = null;
   synchronized (session) {
     token = (String) session.getAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_ATTR_NAME);
     if (null==token) {
       token=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       session.setAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_ATTR_NAME, token);
   }
 }
 return token;
}
```

**implement `RequestDataValueProcessor`**

```
public class CSRFRequestDataValueProcessor implements RequestDataValueProcessor {
 ...
 @Override
 public Map<String,String> getExtraHiddenFields(HttpServletRequest request) {
   Map<String,String> hiddenFields = new HashMap<String,String>();
   hiddenFields.put(CSRFTokenManager.CSRF_PARAM_NAME, CSRFTokenManager.getTokenForSession(request.getSession()));
   return hiddenFields;
  }
}
```

**Then define the bean**

```
<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="com...CSRFRequestDataValueProcessor"/>
```

Creadit Reference - http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html

Comment: Spring Faces is on 2.4.1 (too old), I adapted the CSRF part for facelets, I'm looking for some like Spring Faces 4.x at least

Comment: Spring Faces is part of Spring Webflow which is on version 2.4.1. Spring Faces isn't related to Spring or Spring Security... So trying to find a version 4 will yield nothing.

Comment: Regarding the answer using a `RequestDataValueProcessor` will not work this will only work in the case where Springs own `form` tag is used, I highly doubt that that is available for JSF. Next to that [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/support/csrf/CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.html) already has integration for that so there is no need to write your own.

Comment: Spring Security taglibs for facelets is only authorize tag but for jsp are authentication, accesscontrollist, csrfInput, csrfMetaTags, etc.